# kylin.sh command inubuntu error

Tags: command, kylin

I'm trying to run kylin.sh to start kylin in ubuntu. Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error. Since I'm not so good in ubuntu please help me out figure the error.

Here is the message I get while running the command.

KYLIN_HOME is set to /usr/local/apache-kylin-1.5.4.1-bin
cat: invalid option -- '1'
Try 'cat --help' for more information.
-mkdir: Not enough arguments: expected 1 but got 0
Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -mkdir [-p]  ...
failed to create , Please make sure the user has right to access

Any kind of suggestion for the error is appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is not a programming question, and is thus off-topic for this site.  Try over at [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: All right, thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Replace the content of `get-properties.sh` by this:

```
if [ $# != 1 ]
then
    echo 'invalid input'
    exit -1
fi

result=`cat ${KYLIN_HOME}/conf/kylin.properties | grep -w "^$1" | grep -v '^#' | awk -F= '{ n = index($0,"="); print substr($0,n+1)}' | cut -c 1- |tail -1`
echo $result
```